# SQL Server is copying my data into a new row instead of using the original data and just assigning the foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public partial class TSS_Filter
{
    [Key]
    public int filter_id { get; set; }

    public int? rackId { get; set; }

    public virtual TSS_Rack TSS_Rack { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public partial class TSS_Rack
{
    public TSS_Rack()
    {
        TSS_Filter = new HashSet<TSS_Filter>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int rack_id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TSS_Filter> TSS_Filter { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to save the filter with a Rack object it takes the copy of the Rack object in the database and re creates it with the next sequential primary key and all of the rest of the data is the same.

Example:

```
Rack Table:
1 - rack 1 - datais here <- the rack row I want to use for the foreign key
2 - rack 1 - datais here <- the created copy row that actually get assigned
```

Why is sql server/entity framework behaving this way?

Save code:

```
        using (ScaleManagerEntities SSDb = new ScaleManagerEntities())
        {
            TSS_Filter filter = new TSS_Filter();
            filter.TSS_Rack = SelectedRack;

            SSDb.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: so where is `SelectedRack` assigned..? where are you telling the `SSDb` which key id to update..? is there a where clause associated with the entity..?

Comment: Selected Rack is assign thought a combobox in WPF. I make a call to the database to get all possible racks. And do I have to tell it the exact key to update? Doesn't entity framework look for the object in the database before creating a new one?

Comment: @MethodMan If I do a database lookup for the rack within the same using context for the rack and assign that it works as expected. Seems weird though I thought It would be able to recognize an object with the same ID as the same object between using the database

Comment: yeah and I am thinking that without a where clause it would update all because it does not know what ID it's updating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        using (ScaleManagerEntities SSDb = new ScaleManagerEntities())
        {
            TSS_Rack rack = SSDb.TSS_Rack.Where(r => r.rack_id == SelectedRack.rack_id).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (TSS_Filter filter in Filters)
            {

                filter.createdAt = DateTime.Now;
                filter.isUsed = false;
                filter.TSS_Rack = rack;

                SSDb.TSS_Filter.Add(filter);
            }

            SSDb.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If I looked up with rack within the same context as I did save it the Database didn't have any trouble knowing it was the same object. Seems weird it wouldn't just know that they were the same row in the DB based on the RackId.

Would appreciate any that could make the database recognize the Object outside of the same using session. Thanks.